# CLI tool like Bitcoin Explorer (bx) for BIP85? multisig?

Tags: multi-signature, mnemonic-seed, bip85-deterministic-entropy

Looking for a CLI tool like Bitcoin Explorer (bx) that will generate multiple seeds/mnemonics from a single entropy string, as per BIP85

Also one that allows for a decent  multisig scheme? Or if not an automated tool, maybe a recommendation for HowTo docs that are pretty well accepted?

Not worried at this point about transaction signing, but establishing good receiving address and cold storage opsec.

Let me know if these should actually be separate questions, they may just be intertwined in my brain only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended my [bitcoin bash tools](https://github.com/grondilu/bitcoin-bash-tools) library today to support bip-85.  You can check it out.

I don't have any support for multisig at the moment, though.

Answer (score 0):

BTC HD Wallet is BIP85 compatible

Bitcoin wallet generator, supporting bip39 / bip32, bip44, bip49, bip84, slip132 (Multi-signature P2WSH in P2SH, Multi-signature P2WSH)

not established? verify everything

Looks very flexible

- from-entropy-hex
- from-mnemonic
- from-master-xprv
- from-bip39-seed

Wasabi import file format (inspired by ColdCard)

also create a watch only wallet from extended pub key

https://github.com/scgbckbone/btc-hd-wallet